# Dreamfactory :How to use MySQL aggregate functions in queries?

Tags: mysql, api, rest, dreamfactory

I am using Dreamfactory version 2.1.0 with MySQL database. I have created a virtual field named `vcol1` for `SUM(col1)` in the Schema, marked it as aggregate and defined the field, and specified the return type. But when I mention the field as `vcol1` in the `api_docs`,I get value **`0`** for all records.

How can I query the  following using api?

```
SELECT col0,SUM(col1)
FROM tablename
WHERE col2=x
GROUP BY col3
```

Comment: read this stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and clarify your question

Comment: You need to show your code if you expect anyone to help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
http://{server}/api/v2/{service}/_table/{table_name}?filter=col2=x&group=col3&fields=col3,col0,vcol1`
```